# Recommended Bluetooth Receiver for Speakers?

Tags: speakers

I have normal speakers which can be connected via a 3.5mm jack. I want to use those speakers wirelessly with help of bluetooth, so is there any bluetooth receiver device for such type of speakers ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed there are a few bluetooth receivers out there you can buy.

Altough I don't own one, products made by Logitech never disappointed me. So I'd recommend the Logitech Wireless Speaker Adapter for Bluetooth Audio Devices. It also got good customer reviews on amazon.com.

[image: Logitech Wireless Speaker Adapter for Bluetooth Audio Devices]

It features the needed 3,5mm Headphone jack and supports many bluetooth devices(including Android phones and iPhones).

But please do your own research before asking these questions and check out [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Stackexchange is not the platform for shopping questions. Also see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site for further information.

Sites that I find useful before purchasing hardware are [The Wirecutter](http://thewirecutter.com/) and the subreddit [/r/BuyItForLife](http://www.reddit.com/r/BuyItForLife/). The last one especially is the place to go for such types of questions.